# How to put SQL WHERE clause with integer value in VB.Net?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, where-clause

Okay I'm sorry if this was too easy for you but I'm kinda confused and I don't know what approach I need for this. Please bear with me.

In SQL Server Management Studio I have a query that gets the active User information.

```
SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo WHERE IsActive = '1'
```

My problem is that I don't know or rather I forgot how to put where clause with integer value in VB.Net.

Here's my code

```vb
Public Shared Function FnGetUserID() As List(Of String)
        Dim lstUserID As New List(Of String)

        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand()
        Try
            cmd.Connection = DBConn.getConn()
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Connection.Open()

            Dim sql As String = ""
            sql += " SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo"

            cmd.CommandText = sql

            Dim sqlRdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While sqlRdr.Read
                lstUserID.Add(sqlRdr.Item("UserID").ToString)
            End While

            cmd.Connection.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()
        Catch ex As Exception
            cmd.Dispose()
            'lstSite = Nothing
        End Try

        Return lstUserID
    End Function
```

and I came up with this

```vb
Dim sql As String = ""
sql += " SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo WHERE IsActive = @IsActive"

cmd.CommandText = sql

parameter.ParameterName = "@IsActive"
parameter.Value = "1"
cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter)
```

I don't know if this is right or not.
Please help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: if it is parameter that will always be 1, why not just ' SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo where IsActive = 1'

Comment: have you ever tried? are you getting any errors? what errors?

Comment: _I don't know if this is right or not._. Have you tried it?

Comment: Do you get any errors? If so, what is the error? Do you execute your command? If so, how?

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply. Yes I've tried it already in window service and I'm still testing it if it works correctly. I didn't get any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks correct.

If the column IsActive is an Integer, you can set the command text to be either of the following:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo WHERE IsActive = 1"

"SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo WHERE IsActive = '1'"
```

If you want to use the parameter, you are correct with using the command text:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo WHERE IsActive = @IsActive"
```

When using the parameter you have to make sure you add it to the sql command object as you are doing:

```
    Dim parameter As SqlClient.SqlParameter = New SqlClient.SqlParameter

    parameter.ParameterName = "@IsActive"
    parameter.Value = "1"
    cmd.Parameters.Add(parameter)
```

You must add the parameter to the command before you call ExecuteReader.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Parameters.AddWithValue`

```
Dim sql = "SELECT DISTINCT UserID FROM tblUserInfo WHERE IsActive = @IsActive"

cmd.CommandText = sql

Dim isActive = 1

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IsActive", isActive)
```